# How to convert a quadratic term in terms of matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and vectors ${\bf c} $ and ${\bf v}$.

Now suppose that we have a matrix ${\bf B}$ where $(i,j)$ coordinate of ${\bf B}$ is given by 
\begin{align}
b_{ij}=({\bf a}_i^r{\bf v}^T +c_i) a_{ji},
\end{align} 
where ${\bf a}_i^r$is the $i$th row of ${\bf A}$ and  $a_{ji}$ are $(j,i)$ entry of ${\bf A}$.

My question: How to write ${\bf B}$ in terms of matrix operations on ${\bf A} $ and vectors ${\bf c} $ and ${\bf v}$?

This appears to be some kind of quadratic form. However, I cannot characterize it exactly.  I am sure that the term $({\bf a}_i^r{\bf v}^T +c_i)$ would lead to ${\bf A}{\bf v}+{\bf c}$.  However, I am not sure how to incorporate the $a_{ji}$ term.

Answer (score 1):

The definition does not make sense. Both $\mathbf a_i^r$ and $\mathbf v^T$ are row vectors. They cannot be multiplied. I suppose you mean $b_{ij}=(\mathbf a_i^r\mathbf v+c_i)a_{ji}$ instead. If this is the case, then $\mathbf B=\left[(\mathbf A\mathbf v+\mathbf c)\mathbf e^T\right]\circ\mathbf A^T$, where $\mathbf e^T=(1,1,\ldots,1)$ and the symbol $\circ$ denotes Hadamard (entrywise) multiplication of two matrices.